# list full string after split the string after comma asp.net C#

Tags: asp.net

I have a string of fruits apple and pear, i want to split this string after "," and display output as

```
apple
pear
```

I have tried to use below method but it will only display pear

```
string[] tokens = str.Split(',');
string last = tokens[tokens.Length-1];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `String#Replace`, to simply replace all commas by newline:

```
string input = "apple,pear";
string output = input.Replace(',', '\n');
Console.WriteLine(input);
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

This prints:

```
apple,pear
apple
pear
```